# How unsafe can be the usage of "Unsafe" in SQL CLR?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, clr, sqlclr

Since clients do not have access to the SQL CLR assemblies, it is only our own bugs that we have to fear. And with careful usage, "unsafe" can be quite safe. What do you think?

Comment: I think your question is both too vague and only going to illicit opinions.

Comment: Sean is correct.  Risks exist everywhere, low probability events happen all the time.  Only you and your organization can deterimine what is an acceptable risk.

Comment: What I meant is, that the fact that an assembly is marked as "unsafe" does not mean that it is really unsafe or that our usage is - it just means that we are on our own. Am I wrong?

Comment: I believe low probability events can happen even with "safe" assemblies. Bugs can happen.

Comment: So does it make the "unsafe" concept vague?

Comment: From SQL Server 2017 [all CLR is treated as unsafe by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/clr-strict-security)

Comment: Just added some info to my answer, starting with 2nd paragraph...

Comment: So what Lorin_F commented above is 100% correct; even with a `SAFE` assembly you can get into situations which is "dangerous" to the SQL Server instance you are running on. In a fairly recent [blog-post](http://www.nielsberglund.com/2017/07/02/sql-server-2017-sqlclr-and-permissions/) I wrote that the permission set, is mostly an indication of how badly you can shoot yourself in the foot: 
`SAFE`: You cannot shoot yourself in the foot any more than what you can do with T-SQL. 
`EXTERNAL_ACCESS`: You can definitely shoot yourself in the foot.
`UNSAFE`: You are free to blow your head off.

Comment: @NielsBerglund - I interpret the statement *A CLR assembly created with PERMISSION_SET = SAFE may be able to access external system resources, call unmanaged code, and acquire sysadmin privileges..* to mean exactly what it says. SQL CLR was suddenly removed from Azure with very little notice so I assume flaws must have been found where malicious safe assemblies could circumvent security.

Comment: @MartinSmith - So do I, in my aforementioned [blogpost](http://www.nielsberglund.com/2017/07/02/sql-server-2017-sqlclr-and-permissions/), however, I tried to execute `UNSAFE` code, without having created the assembly as `UNSAFE`, and it wouldn't let me do it (I had to mark it as `UNSAFE` to be able to execute). So maybe there is  - as you say - an edge case whereby you can circumvent security. In my world it doesn't matter that much, seeing that most of our assemblies in our main OLTP 24/7 highly transactional databases requires `UNSAFE` regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Unsafe" isn't always a matter of who is executing the code, but what code is being executed and/or how it was coded. `UNSAFE` Assemblies allow for code that can, even in the ideal / proper usage, either destabilize SQL Server, or allow for security holes, or allow for odd / unexpected behavior. For example, using `TimeZoneInfo` to convert times between time zones requires unsafe even though it should be a somewhat simple calculation. The problem is that somewhere in that code base there is something that causes a memory leak. This has been experienced by folks who try to do bulk updates of date columns. `UNSAFE` is also used for code that *could* be SAFE but hasn't been verified by Microsoft, so it cannot be guaranteed. And in terms of using unsupported .NET Framework libraries, those are not only not guaranteed to work as expected (or not have memory leaks or be thread safe), but they aren't even guaranteed to work across any future .NET Framework update (case in point: `ServiceModel` became mixed-mode in .NET Framework v 4.0, so starting in SQL Server 2012, anyone who had imported `ServiceModel` into SQL Server 2005, 2008, or 2008 R2 could no longer import it and had to rewrite a bunch of code if they wanted to upgrade SQL Server).

But back to the question, how unsafe can it be when you control the code? You might not allow for any security holes, but you can definitely get yourself into situations of memory leaks and "odd" behavior due to shared memory (i.e. static variables) / synchronization issues that are really hard to reproduce and debug. For example, the following is a question on DBA.StackExchange about an error that started happening only when the system started calling the SQLCLR function(s) much more frequently. The problem was due to using a static variable to store stated, and then multiple sessions overwriting the values and getting unexpected values back when they went to read from that variable:

[SQLCLR assembly throws error when multiple queries run simultaneously](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126574/sqlclr-assembly-throws-error-when-multiple-queries-run-simultaneously/126583#126583)

Can `UNSAFE` Assemblies be used "safely"? Of course. If you are using a static variable for caching, and reload if it is ever null, that should be fine. Or, it is *possible* to load an unsupported .NET Framework library (which nearly always must be marked as `UNSAFE`) but only use "safe" methods within it (just because an Assembly has code that is "unsafe" doesn't mean that the "unsafe" code will ever be executed). The downsides there are: 1) you aren't aware of ALL of what those libraries are doing, even if you do check out some of it on reference.microsoft.com; and 2) you still face the possibility that at some point that library will be updated to be mixed-mode and then you have to rewrite everything.

Comment: Why is it OK to possibly have memory leaks in .Net Framework libraries used on servers, but not so when using these dlls inside SQL Server ?

Comment: @Lorin_F I wouldn't say that it's "OK" that memory leaks happen anywhere. Ideally they would never happen. But, SQL Server's CLR host is highly restricted, not just related to memory leaks, and I suspect it has to do with how protective SQL Server is over memory (it requires as much physical memory as you can give it) and the lack of built-in fixes for memory consumption: Windows apps destroy their AppDomain upon exit. ASP.NET can be set to recycle if memory goes over a specified amount. SQL Server only unloads the AppDomain if there isn't enough memory left. That cycling reduces performance.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Rutzky.
Anyway, given that system libraries are used by millions of people, wouldn't it be safe to assume that all issues regarding them are known issues and are usually solved?

Comment: @Lorin_F I would never say "_all issues regarding them are known issues and are usually solved_" about any software anywhere, ever. Even if 1 billion people use the libraries, not all issues are known, and not all known issues are solved. And even if solved, that doesn't mean that the updated code makes it everywhere. Still, remember that the context is running within SQL Server. There are operations that are not bugs but are still dangerous in this specific environment, especially shared-memory and multi-threading issues. There are likely also internationalization issues in some libraries.